# PHP version issue when installing Craft 3 using Composer

Tags: installation, craft3, composer

Why do I get the error when I try to install Craft 3?

```
composer create-project craftcms/craft Documents/Development/Project -s beta
```

The error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                           
Could not find package craftcms/craft with stability stable 
in a version installable using your PHP version 5.6.30.
```

I am running PHP 7.1.

Answer (score 3):

You are running PHP 5.6.30 on the command line (read the error message), which you can also verify with `php -v`.

To swap the PHP, you should add the path to your preferred PHP executable to your shell’s configuration file (e.g. ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc, ~/.zshrc).

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/bin:$PATH"
```

Another option is to ignore the PHP requirement using [`--ignore-platform-reqs`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project)

```
composer create-project craftcms/craft . -s beta --ignore-platform-reqs
```

and then [fake the PHP version](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) in the project’s composer.json for later updates

```
"config": {
  "optimize-autoloader": true,
  "platform": {"php": "7.0"}
},
```